# Show that $A+I$ is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A $\in \mathbb{F}^{n \times n}$. If $AA^T = I$ and $\det A < 0$, show that $A+I$ is singular.

So far, I attempted to use the result that $\det (A+I) = \det A + \det I + tr(A)$ to show that $\det(A+I) = 0$ in order to conclude that $A+I$ is singular.

Do anyone have an alternative to prove this statement?

Comment: Since $A$ is orthogonal, all of its eigenvalues are either $1$ or $-1$, and since $\det A<0$ at least one of them is $-1$, which means $A+I$ has $0$ as one of its eigenvalues.

Comment: @Vim But $\mathbb{F}$ may not be $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @velutluna good point. But i suspect the statement would be wrong for $\Bbb C$.

Comment: perhaps may be then $det(A) $ may be complex and then $det(A)<0$ will not make any sense.

Comment: Is the result $\det (A+I) = \det A + \det I + tr(A)$ true always?

Comment: @MANMAID well, I think it fails for even one by one matrices...

Comment: @Vim just take $A=-I$

Comment: @MANMAID I guess that $\mathbb F$ must have a partial order compatible with the field operations. On could define such an partial order on $\mathbb C$ by using the order on $\mathbb R$ together with $z\le z$ otherwise. Then $\det A<0$ would make sense.

Comment: @Vim Apparently the statement is true for any partially ordered field where $0\le 1$, this includes $\mathbb C$ supplied with a suitable PO. Especially it's true for any field if we replace the condition $\det A<0$ with $\det A\ne 1$.

Comment: It is not true that the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix are $\pm 1$, think of a rotation matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can apparently assume that the field $\Bbb{F}$ is ordered. Otherwise it does not make sense to say that the determinant is negative. Most obviously we can exclude fields of characteristic $p>0$.

We were given that $AA^T=I$. Therefore $\det(A)^2=\det(AA^T)=1$, and we can conclude that $\det A=\pm1$. The assumption $\det A<0$ thus leaves $\det A=-1$ as the only alternative (an axiom of an ordered field is that $1>0$ and it follows that $-1<0$).

But, we can then calculate as follows
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det (A+I)&=\det(A+AA^T)\\
&=\det(A(I+A^T))\\
&=\det A \cdot \det(I+A^T)\\
&=(-1)\cdot \det(I+A).
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
\det(I+A)=-\det(I+A).
$$
In a field of characteristic $\neq 2$ the equation $x=-x$ forces $x=0$. Therefore $\det(I+A)=0$, and $A+I$ is singular.

Comment: NIce! but how $\det(I+A^{T}) = \det(I+A)$,any trick to this?

Comment: The transposes have the same determinant $(I+A)^T=I^T+A^T=I+A^T$.

Comment: As far as I see it you don't have to rely on a total order for the question to make sense. The only thing you need in the last step is that $\det A\ne 1$ which is guaranteed if $0\le 1$.

Comment: A nice observation @skyking.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if any one eigenvalue of a matrix say $B$ is zero then $B$ is a singular matrix.Since determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues.

In your case $A$ is an Orthogonal matrix!

and since $det(A) < 0$ implying there is atleast one eigenvalue $-1$ .

Now we need to analyse matrix $A+I$ , since $A$ has an eigenvalue $-1$ so $A+I$ will have an eigenvalue as $0$ implying $det(A+I) = 0$ and hence singular.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if the field we're working above isn't the reals?

Comment: Yes,good catch.I think if its not then there is a possibility that $det(A)$ may be complex and $det(A)<0$ may not make any sense?

Comment: Real orthogonal matrices can have any complex numbers on the unit circle as their eigenvalues. Consider $$R(\theta)=\pmatrix{\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\cr \sin\theta&\cos\theta\cr}.$$ Its eigenvalues are $e^{\pm i\theta}$.

Comment: Nice! but in your case I think in your example $det(R(\theta)) = 1 > 0$ , just as per the question i thought that since it is true for all orthogonal matrices $A$ there may be a case that $det(A)$ is complex and since user has added a condition that $det(A)<0$,then comparing them wouldnot make any sense?

Comment: Correct, @BAYMAX. My example matrix has $\det =1$. The point was to refute the claim that the eigenvalues can be $\pm1$ only. If the determinant of an orthogonal matrix is $-1$, it turns out that then $-1$ must be an eigenvalue, but that needs to be proven first I think :-)

Comment: Yes we need to prove that first @JyrkiLahtonen,BTW is my answer incorrect?.